# qt5: error: no member named 'setMarkdown' in 'QTextEdit'

Tags: qt, qt5

After I edited the GUI in Qt-Creator and when I want to run software in Debug/Release mode, I always get an error of "no member named 'setMarkdown' in 'QTextEdit'".

The only way to solve this issue is to replace all the from "setMarkdown" to "setWindowTitle" manually.

If any way to can solve this issue automatically, Thanks!

ERROR:

```
ui_mainwindow.h:685: error: no member named 'setMarkdown' in 'QTextEdit'
./ui_mainwindow.h:685:43: error: no member named 'setMarkdown' in 'QTextEdit'
        test->setMarkdown(QString());
        ~~~~~~~  ^
```

Comment: what is your Qt version? setMarkdown is available for Qt >= 5.14

Comment: my Qt Creator 4.15.1, Based on Qt 5.15.2 (Clang 11.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Comment: One thing is QtCreator and another is Qt. The message you indicate tells me that the version of QtCreator is 4.15.1 and it was compiled with Qt 5.15.2 , it does not indicate that the application was compiled with that version. What is the output of `qmake -v`?

Comment: Oh! my Qmake -v is 5.12.11, and this version is lower than 5.14 as you said. After I change it to 5.14.11, it works! Thank you so much!!